# ResourceHttpRequestHandler : resource not found / image from local directories

Tags: spring, spring-boot, resources, static-content

I am using Spring Boot. I try using images from local resources to show it on webpage.

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
public class MvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Value("{upload.path}")
    private String uploadPath;

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/img/**")
                .addResourceLocations("file://" + uploadPath + "/");
    }

}
```

File `application.properties`

```
upload.path=/e:/fortests
```

when I am trying to `localhost:8080/img/image.jpeg`

I received this log

```
2018-12-31 02:46:32.242 DEBUG 11972 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] 
o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/img/image.jpeg", parameters={}
2018-12-31 02:46:32.245 DEBUG 11972 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] 
o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to 
ResourceHttpRequestHandler ["file://{upload.path}/"]
2018-12-31 02:46:32.250 DEBUG 11972 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] 
o.s.w.s.r.ResourceHttpRequestHandler     : Resource not found
2018-12-31 02:46:32.251 DEBUG 11972 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] 
o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 404 NOT_FOUND
2018-12-31 02:46:32.253 DEBUG 11972 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] 
o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : "ERROR" dispatch for GET "/error", parameters={}
2018-12-31 02:46:32.259 DEBUG 11972 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] 
s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to public 
org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2018-12-31 02:46:32.267 DEBUG 11972 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] 
o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Selected 'text/html' given 
[text/html, text/html;q=0.8]
2018-12-31 02:46:32.269 DEBUG 11972 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] 
o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Exiting from "ERROR" dispatch, status 404
```

if not using `path.upload` property and make it hard-coded in class

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/img/**")
            .addResourceLocations("file://e:/fortest/");
}
```

log:

```
2018-12-31 02:51:03.120 DEBUG 13408 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] 
o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/img/image.jpeg", parameters={}
2018-12-31 02:51:03.121 DEBUG 13408 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] 
o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to 
ResourceHttpRequestHandler ["file://e:/fortest/"]
2018-12-31 02:51:07.687 DEBUG 13408 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] 
o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Failed to complete request: 
java.net.UnknownHostException: e
2018-12-31 02:51:07.689 ERROR 13408 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/]. 
[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] 
in context with path [] threw exception
```

at first I received whitelabel page, now I just received "non-loaded" image. What am I doing wrong, and what better way to handle local resources if not this for me? and yes, I have `image.jpeg` in `/e:/fortest`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**(1)** You are using Windows operating system. This snippet

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/img/**")
            .addResourceLocations("file://e:/fortest/");
}
```

Line

```
.addResourceLocations("file://e:/fortest/");
```

should be

```
.addResourceLocations("file:///E:/fortest/");
```

**(2)**

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
```

should be

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class MvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
```

Comment: Thank you, but what i still have problem with property "upload.path". any solutions for that? just do not want to hard-code inside class
changed it to `upload.path=/E:/fortest`

Comment: I am so sorry for this question again.
forgot about expression $ like `@Value("${upload.path}")
    private String uploadPath;`
i got an answer thanks alot!